# iOS: Table View (with FetchedResultsController) as Subview of another view

Tags: ios, core-data, tableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I've followed the CS193p on Itunes and am programming now my own app. In the course they have a `CoreDataViewController` (which is a subclass of `TableViewController` with all the necessary `NSFetchedResults` methods in it). With this I got every `tableview` running quickly. However I want no a view (at the top of my screen) with table view below for only about half the screen.

I've only found tutorials how to embed a normal table view into a normal `viewcontroller` and hook up the `datasource` and `delegate` outlets. But how would I do this with the `NSFetchedResultsController`?
I guess I have to do it the same and then copy all the functions from the original `CoreDataViewController` in my own `viewcontroller` to handle the fetched results?
Or how would i do that?

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen how the CoreDataViewController was implemented.  But yes, you would follow the normal step to set the NsFetchedResultsController.  Or you can just create an instance of CoreDataViewController and add its tableView view to the bottom half of your view controller's subview.

Comment: thanks, the implementation you could find here under lesson 14 CoreData http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/.

Comment: But how do you mean I could create an instance? How would the main view controller then handle this CoreDataViewController instance? I've never seen that?